# c# need help combining if statement with char array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, user-input

I'm an absolute beginner at C# and recently tried to create my own to do list as a console app.
So what i want to do is give the user the option to chose with 'a' 'e' or 'd' and thought i could use that in an if statement.

Here is how far I got:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("                           To-Do-List");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("Task capacity is 10");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("[a] Add Task");
    Console.WriteLine("[e] Edit Task");
    Console.WriteLine("[d] Delete Task");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    Console.WriteLine("select action");
    char[] userAction = { 'a', 'e', 'd', };

    if (userAction[0])
    {

    }
}
```

when I try to implement the `userAction` variable in the if condition it tells me it cant be converted into a boolean and since I am not really confident with syntax and all that I don't know if that's even the right approach - do i have to use something else instead of an if statement? i would want the program to react for example if the user presses 'a' with something like `Console.WriteLine("choose a name for your task");`

Comment: You need to read a single character from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line userAction[0] will return a char value of 'a' as 'a' is the first element in your array.

You need to add a bool expression (true, false) in your if statement.

Please have a look at the example below:

```
        Console.WriteLine("                           To-Do-List");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("Task capacity is 10");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("[a] Add Task");
        Console.WriteLine("[e] Edit Task");
        Console.WriteLine("[d] Delete Task");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        Console.WriteLine("select action");
        var inputOption = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] userAction = { 'a', 'e', 'd', };

        if (inputOption == userAction[0].ToString()) //example of if statement
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You choose option to Add task");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: But i'm still not sure if i really understand it. Do i have to convert the char into a string because Console.ReadLine(); is expecting a string?

Comment: Yes, you cannot compare a string to a char.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods that will make your life a lot easier:

```
public static string AskString(string question){
  Console.WriteLine(question);
  return Console.ReadLine();
}

public static char AskChar(string question, char[] validChars){
  string input = AskString(question);
  while(input.Length == 0 || (validChars != null && !validChars.Contains(input[0])))
    input = AskString(question);
  
  return input[0];
}

public static int AskInt(string question, int[] validInts){
  string input = AskString(question);
  while(input.Length == 0 || !int.TryParse(input, out int res) || (validInts != null && !validInts.Contains(res)))
    input = AskString(question);
  
  return int.Parse(input);
}
```

Now you can use them in your programs:

```
string name = AskString("How old are you?");

int age = AskInt("What age are you?", null);

int choice = AskInt("Choose 1, 2 or 3?", new[]{1,2,3});

char choice2 = AskChar("Choose A, B or C (case sensitive)?", "ABC".ToCharArray());

if(choice == 1 || choice2 = 'B') 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to implement menu-driven program where you want user to select option to perform certain operation. You can try below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
...
var userAction = 'Y'; //Default assignment to userAction variable
do
{
     Console.WriteLine("[a] Add Task");
     Console.WriteLine("[e] Edit Task");
     Console.WriteLine("[d] Delete Task");
     Console.WriteLine("[y] Exit from Program");
     //Console.Read will give you ability to read action option from an user
     userAction = Console.Read();
     //You can use switch expression as well
     if(Char.ToLower(userAction) == 'a')
     {
         //Perform Add Task action
     }
     else if(Char.ToLower(userAction) == 'e')
     {
         //Perform Edit Task action
     }
     else if(Char.ToLower(userAction) == 'd')
     {
         //Perform Delete Task action
     }
     else if(Char.ToLower(userAction) == 'y')
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exiting from the program");
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid input")
     }
//Do.. while loop will help you to force the user to either press proper options or exit from the program.
}while(Char.ToLower(userAction) == 'y');
}
```